# Protobuf version mismatch in GPflow/TensorFlow optimization when used together with MATLAB engine for Python

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I have some simulation code which is written in MATLAB and I have to run bayesian optimization on that using GPflowOpt. I use the [MATLAB Engine for Python](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav) to retrieve the results of the MATLAB objective function and pass them to my Python optimization code. I installed GPflowOpt ([here](https://gpflowopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#install)) and the MATLAB Engine ([here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html)) according to the instructions and my stripped down version (see below) of [this example code](https://gpflowopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/multiobjective.html) from the GPflowOpt docs works as expected.

```py
import gpflow
import gpflowopt
import matlab.engine
import numpy as np

def vlmop2(x):
    transl = 1 / np.sqrt(2)
    part1 = (x[:, [0]] - transl) ** 2 + (x[:, [1]] - transl) ** 2
    part2 = (x[:, [0]] + transl) ** 2 + (x[:, [1]] + transl) ** 2
    y1 = 1 - np.exp(-1 * part1)
    y2 = 1 - np.exp(-1 * part2)
    return np.hstack((y1, y2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
#    engine = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
#    print('Working dir: ', engine.pwd())

    domain = gpflowopt.domain.ContinuousParameter('x1', -2, 2) + \
             gpflowopt.domain.ContinuousParameter('x2', -2, 2)

    design = gpflowopt.design.LatinHyperCube(11, domain)
    X = design.generate()
    Y = vlmop2(X)

    # One model for each objective
    objective_models = [gpflow.gpr.GPR(X.copy(), Y[:,[i]].copy(), gpflow.kernels.Matern52(2, ARD=True)) for i in range(Y.shape[1])]
    for model in objective_models:
        model.likelihood.variance = 0.01

    hvpoi = gpflowopt.acquisition.HVProbabilityOfImprovement(objective_models)

    # First setup the optimization strategy for the acquisition function
    # Combining MC step followed by L-BFGS-B
    acquisition_opt = gpflowopt.optim.StagedOptimizer([gpflowopt.optim.MCOptimizer(domain, 1000),
                                                       gpflowopt.optim.SciPyOptimizer(domain)])

    # Then run the BayesianOptimizer for 20 iterations
    optimizer = gpflowopt.BayesianOptimizer(domain, hvpoi, optimizer=acquisition_opt, verbose=True)
    result = optimizer.optimize([vlmop2], n_iter=5)

    print(result)
    print(optimizer.acquisition.pareto.front.value)
```

But as soon as I make only one single call to the MATLAB engine somewhere in the code (just uncomment the two lines in my above snippet) execution breaks on line

```py
result = optimizer.optimize([vlmop2], n_iter=5)
```

and I am confronted with some strange error complaining about some Protobuf version number mismatch:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL /tmp/B3p3/glnxa64/protobuf3/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:68] This program requires version 3.8.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 3.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/any.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
```

I read a bit about what Protobuf is, what it does and that it obviously is part of TensorFlow, but I don't have any clue why I could possibly have some version mismatch here. I installed everything inside a virtualenv and reinstalled the **tensorflow** and **protobuf** packages back and forth several times in different versions to no avail. This is an excerpt of the currently installed relevant packages:

```
Package               Version
--------------------- ----------
gpflow                0.5
gpflowopt             0.1.1
matlabengineforpython R2019b
numpy                 1.18.5
protobuf              3.12.2
tensorflow            1.15.3
tensorflow-estimator  1.15.1
```

Strange enough I don't even know why the error message states I have Protobuf version 3.6.1 installed, though the protobuf package clearly is a later version and I don't know where this 3.6.1 version could hide on my system. What's more interesting is that the code works like a charm as long as the MATLAB engine is not involved. But as soon as I just make one single call to `engine.eval(…)` it's over and the code goes south. Interestingly the code still works as long as I just initialize the engine and don't exchange any data with it

I already have used the MATLAB engine on another optimization task using scikit-opt earlier, where I basically did the same (fetch a function result from a MATLAB script and process it in Python) and it worked flawlessly. But somehow it refuses to co-exist with TensorFlow and I don't know where to look into.

I'm happy to provide more information if needed and maybe there is someone out there who has experience with TensorFlow+Protobuf+MATLAB and knows what it's all about.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this? I'm also facing the same protobuf version issue while trying to use Tensorflow inside a simulation software.

Comment: Indeed, I found somewhat of a solution for that particular problem back then. It basically boiled down to not initialize the MATLAB engine until first performing some dummy optimization via GPflowOpt. Since MATLAB comes with it's own percompiled version of the protobuf library, initializing the engine first always led to the protobuf library being loaded that came with MATLAB which in my case was older than the one required by Tensorflow. Switching the order (first run some arbitrary optimization which in turn initializes Tensorflow and init the engine after that) did the trick for me.

Comment: Admittedly, this is somewhat of a cheap solution but since I needed this for my thesis and time was pushing I didn't have the time to investigate which part of the Tensorflow library was responsible for loading the protobuf library. I bet that if you just dig deep enough into the code you will find the specific code part which does just that. And if you're lucky you probably even can make a call to that specific function and you're done - no bickering over some dummy optimizations whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly I forgot about my own question but since apparently I'm not the only one with that, I'll post <del>the</del> my personal solution here:

Basically, it all came down to first execute some arbitrary code which boostraps Tensorflow which in turn loads the protobuf library (presumably for some internal data exchange) before exchanging data with the MATLAB engine.

It seems like data exchange between the Python world and MATLAB is done via protobuf messages. So, if you first execute some dummy Tensorflow code which internally needs the protobuf library, it will happily load the one that you have installed in your local environment and everything is fine. If you instead first exchange some data with the MATLAB engine (like calling `engine.pwd()` as I did in the commented part above), the engine will load the protobuf library which comes built-in with your MATLAB installation first and that one will most likely be older and incompatible with the one that came with your Tensorflow installation.

So what I did in the end was to just perform a dummy optimization over, say, 3 iterations of some dull function like `x^2` to make sure that all parts of Tensorflow were executed before initializing the MATLAB engine and interacting with it.

Maybe there is an even simpler way to force loading the correct protobuf version through Tensorflow but I didn't have the time nor the willingness to dig down that deep. Honestly, back then I stumbled across protobuf for the first time and didn't exactly know what it was for and how to use it. Now, I'd probably just look into Python's protobuf library and see if there's some kind of `init` or `load` function that could do the job.

I hope this description is of any help for everyone who reads it and comes across the same issue.